# Read .gz files inside .tar files without extracting

Tags: python, unix, gzip, tar

I have a .tar file that contains many .gz files inside a folder. Each of these gz files contain a .txt file. Other stackoverflow questions related to this problem are aimed at extracting the files.

I am trying to iteratively read the content of each .txt file without extracting them, because the .tar is large.

First I read the contents of the .tar file:

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("FILE.tar")
tar.getmembers()
```

Or in Unix:

```
tar xvf file.tar -O
```

Then I tried using the tarfile extractfile method, but I'm getting an error: "module 'tarfile' has no attribute 'extractfile'". Besides, I'm not even sure that is the right method.

```
import gzip
for member in tar.getmembers():
    m = tarfile.extractfile(member)
    file_contents = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=m).read()
```

If you want to create an example file to simulate the original file:

```
$ mkdir directory
$ touch directory/file1.txt.gz directory/file2.txt.gz directory/file3.txt.gz
$ tar -c -f file.tar directory
```

---

This is the final version that worked for me after using Mark Adler's suggestion:

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("file.tar")
members = tar.getmembers()

# Here I append the results in a list, because I wasn't able to
# parse the tarfile type returned by .getmembers():
tar_name = []
for elem in members:
    tar_name.append(elem.name)

# Then I changed tarfile.extractfile to tar.extractfile as suggested: 
for member in tar_name:
    # I'm using this because I have other non-gzs in the directory
    if member.endswith(".gz"):    
        m=tar.extractfile(member)
        file_contents = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=m).read()
```

Comment: You haven't made, or at least are not showing, much of an attempt here. Show what you tried, what happened, and what you expected. Do not leave out code. E.g. you show `tar.getmembers()` as having read the contents, but that couldn't have worked unless you did `tar = tarfile.open("FILE.tar")`. You left out the `tar =`.   If you're going to put code in your question, put _exactly_ what you did, not something vaguely similar to what you did.

Comment: Thanks for the observations. Sometime while pasting and reformatting I removed the tar variable.

Comment: You can use `tar.getnames()` to get the list of names directly. And I'll bet what was actually in your working program was `if member.endswith(".gz"):`. Copy and paste is your friend.

Comment: A .tar file does not contain a directory of all members (like in a .zip file) but only a sequence of file headers and file data blocks. If you want to retrieve a list of the members, all headers in the complete file must be read. This can be implemented by seeking to specific positions in the file, but it will read data from various positions in the file from the start to the end. The overall performance might be better if you read one file header, check the file name, extract the data, go to the next file header etc in the order they appear in the archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `tar.extractfile(member)` instead of `tarfile.extractfile(member)`. `tarfile` is the *class*, and doesn't know about the tar file you opened. `tar` is the tarfile *object*, which references the .tar file you opened.

To do it right, use `next()` instead of `getmembers()` or `getnames()`, so that you don't have to read the entire tar file twice:

```
with tarfile.open(sys.argv[1]) as tar:
    while ent := tar.next():
        if ent.name.endswith(".gz"):
            print(gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=tar.extractfile(ent)).read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's unix line / bash command:

To prepare the files:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/githubtraining/hellogitworld.git
$ cd hellogitworld
$ gzip *
$ ls
build.gradle.gz  fix.txt.gz  pom.xml.gz  README.txt.gz  resources  runme.sh.gz  src
$ cd ..
$ tar -cf hellogitworld.tar hellogitworld/
```

Here is how to view its readme:

```
$ tar -Oxf hellogitworld.tar hellogitworld/README.txt.gz | zcat
```

Result:

```
This is a sample project students can use during Matthew's Git class.

Here is an addition by me

We can have a bit of fun with this repo, knowing that we can always reset it to a known good state.  We can apply labels, and branch, then add new code and merge it in to the master branch.

As a quick reminder, this came from one of three locations in either SSH, Git, or HTTPS format:

* git@github.com:matthewmccullough/hellogitworld.git
* git://github.com/matthewmccullough/hellogitworld.git
* https://matthewmccullough@github.com/matthewmccullough/hellogitworld.git

We can, as an example effort, even modify this README and change it as if it were source code for the purposes of the class.

This demo also includes an image with changes on a branch for examination of image diff on GitHub.
```

Note that I'm not associated with those git repository.

## Explanation for tar:

- flag `-x` = extract
- flag `-O` = don't write the file to filesystem but write to STDOUT
- flag `-f` = specify a file

Then the rest is just piping the result to zcat to see the uncompressed plaintext in STDOUT

Comment: This one is great! I am sure to use it in the future whenever I'm not using Python.

Comment: in python you can also use ```os.system("ls")``` to execute system shell (e.g.: bash/sh) command

Answer (score 0):

```
import gzip
import tarfile

with tarfile.TarFile("data.tar", 'r') as tar_fd:
    for files in tar_fd.getnames():
        if files.endswith(".gz"):
            file = tar_fd.extractfile(files)
            file_content = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=file).readline()
            print(file_content)
```

Comment: No, not like this. This reads the tar file twice when it only has to be read once.

Comment: @MarkAdler would you suggest better solution? I was trying out the one you mentioned below,  however it loops to infinity.

Comment: The better solution is in my answer. You need to use `next()`. Works fine for me.